# Threading in Sequence

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I am trying to learn how to write a program which performs a given set of tasks in sequence with the help of threads. For example, Writing a program which have 3 different threads print 1111…, 22222…., 333333……, so that the output will be 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3…..? OR for e.g. 2 threads one is printing odd numbers and other even numbers, but the output should be printed in sequence - i.e. one even and then odd.

I would like to learn how to write similar kind of programs in which different threads print different stuff concurrently and the output should be printed in sequence.

What is the basic concept in writing these programs. Can we use ThreadPools/Executors for the purpose ? For e.g. can we use

```
ExecutorService exectorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

Can we use Future, FurtureTask, Callable, execute, submit ...? I know these concepts but I am not able to connect the dots for solving the above scenarios.

Please guide me how to go about writing these kind of programs using multithreading / concurrency.

I have written a program using wait()/notifyAll(). Following is the program. I am not executing the consumer as I am printing the whole sequence at the end. Also I am limiting the capacity of the queue to be 15. So I am basically printing the odd / even range till 15.

```
public class ProduceEven implements Runnable {

private final List<Integer> taskQueue; 
private final int           MAX_CAPACITY;

public ProduceEven (List<Integer> sharedQueue, int size) {
    this.taskQueue = sharedQueue; 
    this.MAX_CAPACITY = size; 
}


@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int counter = 0; 

    while (counter < 15) {

        try {
            produce(counter++);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}

private void produce (int i) throws InterruptedException {

    synchronized (taskQueue) {

        while (taskQueue.size() == MAX_CAPACITY) {

            System.out.println("Queue is full : "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is waiting , size: "+ taskQueue.size());
            taskQueue.wait();
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        if(i%2==0) {
            taskQueue.add(i);
        }
            taskQueue.notifyAll();
        }
    }
```

}

```
public class ProduceOdd implements Runnable {

private final List<Integer> taskQueue; 
private final int           MAX_CAPACITY;

public ProduceOdd (List<Integer> sharedQueue, int size) {
    this.taskQueue = sharedQueue; 
    this.MAX_CAPACITY = size; 
}


@Override
public void run() {

    int counter = 0; 

    while (counter < 15) {

        try {
            produce(counter++);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}

private void produce (int i) throws InterruptedException {

    synchronized (taskQueue) {

        while (taskQueue.size() == MAX_CAPACITY) {

            System.out.println("Queue is full : "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is waiting , size: "+ taskQueue.size());
            taskQueue.wait();
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        if(i%2==1) {
            taskQueue.add(i);           
        }           
        taskQueue.notify();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class OddEvenExampleWithWaitAndNotify {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> taskQueue = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        int MAX_CAPACITY = 15;
        Thread tProducerEven = new Thread(new ProduceEven(taskQueue, MAX_CAPACITY), "Producer Even");
        Thread tProducerOdd = new Thread(new ProduceOdd(taskQueue, MAX_CAPACITY), "Producer Odd");
        tProducerEven.start();
        tProducerOdd.start();

        try {
            tProducerEven.join();
            tProducerOdd.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListIterator listIterator = taskQueue.listIterator();

        System.out.println("Elements Are:: ");
        while(listIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(listIterator.next()+"  ");
        }
}
```

}

The output which I get is: Elements Are:: 02134657911810131214

The output is all jumbled up. Why is it not in sequence. 01234567891011121314 What am I missing. I would be now trying to make the program using Semaphores. Also how do we make this program using explicit locks?

Comment: Thread are for performing independent tasks. If you want sequential tasks, use a single thread.

Comment: you might want to explore more about thread communication Notify, NotifyAll and Join.

Comment: @sid there is no point for using multi threads for sequential work, unnecessary you will join/block threads, and manage threads, wherein single thread will do the same. Use multiple threads for parallel processing.

Comment: @ankur: That's what I want to achieve using multiple threads for parallel processing ... one thread print even numbers and the other threads prints odd numbers but the output should be one odd no., one even no. till let says n numbers.

Comment: @Helios: I am aware of the concept of wait, notify, notifyAll, join ... I have also done a program about producer / consumer using wait, notify, notifyAll but for this particular questions I am not able to connect the dots .. how to go about achieving it.

Comment: you can look at locks to synchronize execution..while Thread1 wishes to right it will acquire lock and block Thread2 from execution..once done then Thread1 will release the lock and allow Thread2 to acquire lock and execute

Comment: Re, "That's what I want to achieve using multiple threads for parallel processing."  No.  Printing numbers in sequence is not parallel processing.  Printing numbers in sequence is _sequential_ processing.  Using threads for that is simply the wrong thing to do.  If you say that you want to do A and B in _parallel tasks_, then what you are saying is you don't care which one happens first.  That's what "parallel" means.

Comment: @sid does any of the below answer solves your query ? If yes please accept one answer.

Comment: @anirban: not actually.... I am not able to understand the solutions provided so I have built my own solution after reading all the answers ... but want to know why my solution is not working as expected.

Comment: Well there is no need to implement all the concepts & tools in one single problem. This is simple example, one thread is producing odd and another is producing even. But they have to know when other thread has done printing only then current thread can proceed and print then let other thread know. Let me give you another solution on your line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `ExecutorService` as a starting point to run your threads. You can also create and start your Threads manually, that would make no difference.

The important thing is that your Threads will run in parallel if you do not synchronize them (i.e., they have to wait for one another). To synchronize you can, e.g. use [Semaphores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) or other thread communication mechanisms.

You wrote in the comments you have written a producer/consumer program. It's a bit of the same thing. Each time the 1-Thread produces a 1, the 2-Thread must know that it can now produce a 2. When it is finished, it must let the 3-Thread know that it must produce a 3. The basic concepts are the same. Just the threads have both producer and consumer roles.

Comment: I have seen some examples in other sites ... they have used a shared variable ..... is that similar to the queue (BlockingQueue) which we use in producer / consumer example of BlockingQueue. ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is one sample program to print Odd and Even using two thread and using thread synchronization among them.
Also we have used Executor framework which is not mandatory, you can create thread using new Thread() as well. For quick prototype I have used system.exit() which can be replaced with graceful shutdown of threads like, interruption and all.

```
package com.ones.twos.threes;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class OnesTwos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlockingQueue<Integer> bq1 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(100);
        BlockingQueue<Integer> bq2 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(100);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        try {
            bq1.put(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        executorService.submit(new OddEven(bq1, bq2));
        executorService.submit(new OddEven(bq2, bq1));
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public static class OddEven implements Runnable {

        BlockingQueue<Integer> bq1;
        BlockingQueue<Integer> bq2;

        public OddEven(BlockingQueue<Integer> bq1, BlockingQueue<Integer> bq2) {
            this.bq1 = bq1;
            this.bq2 = bq2;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    int take = bq1.take();
                    System.out.println(take);
                    bq2.offer(take + 1);
                    if (take > 20)
                        System.exit(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mycode is also similar to Anirban's, except I am not using executor framework,

```
public class TestThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean bol = new Boolean(true);
        (new Thread(new Odd(bol), "odd")).start();
        (new Thread(new Even(bol), "even")).start();
    }
}

public class Even implements Runnable {
    private Boolean flag;
    public Even(Boolean b) {
        this.flag = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 2; i < 20; i = i + 2) {
            synchronized (flag) {
                try {
                 System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+i);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    flag.notify();
                    flag.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

public class Odd implements Runnable {
    private Boolean flag;
    public Odd(Boolean b) {
        this.flag = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i = i + 2) {
            synchronized (flag) {
                try {
                 System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+i);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    flag.notify();
                    flag.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By establishing the thread pool of 3 `(ExecutorService exectorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);` you are essentilly limiting the executor capacity to 3 and other incoming threads will be on hold. If you want to run them in paralel you can just submit them at once. If you want to wait for each other and want to find out the result I suggest you use Callable. Personally I really like [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) because after submiting it you can just call the `get` method of [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), wait for a returned value from the executed thread and then continue to the next one. From the API you can see this:

> /**
>        * Submits a value-returning task for execution and returns a
>        * Future representing the pending results of the task. The
>        * Future's {@code get} method will return the task's result upon
>        * successful completion.
>        *
>        *
>
> * If you would like to immediately block waiting
>        * for a task, you can use constructions of the form
>        * {@code result = exec.submit(aCallable).get();}

And a very good example [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6). If you go for the Callable alternative then you don't need a Thread pool. Just a normal executor is fine. Remember to shut the executor down in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyNumber {
    int i = 1;
}

class Task implements Runnable {
    MyNumber myNumber;
    int id;

    Task(int id, MyNumber myNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.myNumber = myNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (myNumber) {
                while (myNumber.i != id) {
                    try {
                        myNumber.wait(); //Wait until Thread with correct next number
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(id);
                if (myNumber.i == 1) {
                    myNumber.i = 2;
                } else if (myNumber.i == 2) {
                    myNumber.i = 3;
                } else {
                    myNumber.i = 1;
                }
                myNumber.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In main method:

```
  MyNumber myNumber = new MyNumber();
  new Thread(new Task(1, myNumber)).start();
  new Thread(new Task(2, myNumber)).start();
  new Thread(new Task(3, myNumber)).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here we have used 2 thread one to print even and another to print odd.
Both are separate and have no relation to each other.
But we have to do a synchronization mechanism between them. Also we need a mechanism to let the ball rolling, i.e. start one thread printing.

Each thread is waiting on condition and after doing it's task it lets other thread work and put ownself in waiting state.

Well happy path works fine, but we need special care when even thread is not in waiting state and the signal() from main fires, in that case even thread will never able to wake up and the program hangs.

So to make sure main thread successfully sends a signal() to even thread and even thread does not miss that we have used Phaser(with party) and checking even thread state in while loop in main.

Code is as below.

```
package com.ones.twos.threes;

import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class OnesTwosTrial2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Lock lk = new ReentrantLock();
        Phaser ph = new Phaser(3); // to let main start the even thread
        Condition even = lk.newCondition();
        Condition odd = lk.newCondition();

        OnesTwosTrial2 onestwostrial2 = new OnesTwosTrial2();
        Thread ev = onestwostrial2.new Evens(lk, even, odd, ph);
        Thread od = onestwostrial2.new Odds(lk, even, odd, ph);

        ev.start();
        od.start();
        System.out.println("in main before arrive");
        ph.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
        System.out.println("in main after arrive");
        // we have to make sure odd and even thread is
        // started and waiting on respective condition.
        // So we used Phaser with 3, because we are having here
        // 3 parties (threads)
        // main, odd,even. We will signal only when all the
        // threads have started.
        // and waiting on conditions.
        while (!Thread.State.WAITING.equals(ev.getState())) {
            System.out.println("waiting");
        }
        lk.lock();
        even.signal();
        lk.unlock();

    }

    class Evens extends Thread {
        Lock lk;
        Condition even;
        Condition odd;
        Phaser ph;

        public Evens(Lock lk, Condition even, Condition odd, Phaser ph) {
            this.lk = lk;
            this.even = even;
            this.odd = odd;
            this.ph = ph;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("even ph");
            int cnt = 0;
            while (cnt < 20) {
                try {
                    lk.lock();
                    ph.arrive();
                    even.await();
                    System.out.println(cnt);
                    cnt += 2;
                    odd.signal();
                    lk.unlock();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Odds extends Thread {
        Lock lk;
        Condition even;
        Condition odd;
        Phaser ph;

        public Odds(Lock lk, Condition even, Condition odd, Phaser ph) {
            this.lk = lk;
            this.even = even;
            this.odd = odd;
            this.ph = ph;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("odd ph");
            int cnt = 1;
            while (cnt < 20) {
                try {
                    lk.lock();
                    ph.arrive();
                    odd.await();
                    System.out.println(cnt);
                    cnt += 2;
                    even.signal();
                    lk.unlock();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```